# Using only the information from a dimension without changing the view

Tags: tableau-api, minimum, dimension

In Tableau 8.3 I have a problem with the information I get from a dimension.

I have "Customer Name" and "Order Date" on rows, and I have chosen to only see the earliest order from each customer - MIN(Order Date). Now I want to see who was the distributor of the particular order, but when I drag "Distribution Center" to rows it edits the view to also contain the earliest order from every distribution center where the customer have made an order. How do I isolate the information of the distribution center to only the earliest order for each customer?

Mikael

Comment: This task is much easier in version 9 using LOD calculations. In v8, the easiest approach uses a simple custom SQL. No time to explain further now, but upgrade if you can and read about LOD calcs.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this would be to rank the dates, then filter out all but the dates with rank 1.

Create a calculated field (I'll call it `[Date Rank Filter]`:

```
RANK_UNIQUE(MIN([Order Date]), 'asc')
```

Go to the Default Table Calculation menu and change "Compute using:" to Distribution Center.

Drag that into Filters and filter everything but 1 out. It will then only show the Distribution Center with the lowest Order Date for each customer.